# reverse list without deleting the initial list

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to reverse a list, but l want to keep my initial list. My function reverse doesn't keep the initial list

For example I want to reverse this:

```
Node n = new Node(1,new Node(12, new Node(34, new Node(3, Node.NIL))));
```

and my function is:

```
public Node reverse(){

  Node p= this;
  if(p == NIL)
      return Node.NIL;


  if(p.n == Node.NIL)
      return p;

  Node rest = p.getNext();
  p.setNext(Node.NIL);
  Node reverseRest = rest.reverse();

  rest.setNext(p);
  return reverseRest;
}
```

The length of my old list after the reverse is 1, and I want it to be 4 for this example. My old and my new list have to have the same length after the reverse.

Comment: @ AntonH my new list is ok , the problem is my old list .my function is recursive

Comment: Show the `Node` class.  What is `p.n`? Is it the same as what is returned by `p.getNext()`?

Comment: @DavidChoweller you can see it above

Comment: I don't see any class definition.

Comment: All I see is a `reverse` function and a line creating the list.

Comment: @DavidChoweller what do you mean ? are you talking about getNext(), getItem ?

Comment: You have not shown the definition of the class `Node`, for example, its instance variables, or its methods.

Comment: @DavidChoweller yes l know . my class Node is like every class Node . i dont want to put my all class. its too big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to preserve the original list your `reverse` method must *create new `Nodes` objects*, rather than making modifications to existing ones.

If you would like to write a recursive `reverse()` that takes no parameters, you can do it as follows:

- Make a new `Node`, and copy this node's content into it; set `next` to `NIL`
- If the next of this node is `NIL`, return the result of previous step
- Otherwise, call `reverse()` on the next
- Take the return value from the previous call, and navigate to its end
- Add the new node from step one to the end, and return the result.

A better approach is to change the signature of `reverse` to take the nodes created so far, in reverse order. This would produce an O(n) algorithm, while the unmodified algorithm above is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: yes l know , but l want to produce an O(n²) algorithm.

Comment: @MohamedMoka Then just follow the steps above, it will give you an O(n²) algorithm.

Comment: @MohamedMoka If you are using a `while` loop anyway, why recurse down again? Your duplication loop is very close to doing it right - all you need is reversing as you go, i.e. setting the next field of the new node to reference the previous node.

Comment: @MohamedMoka, I have added a recursive implementation based on dasblinkenlight's suggestion of an O(n) algorithm to reverse the list.

Comment: @DavidChoweller    beautifull . it works . do you thnk we can do it with only one function ?

Comment: You could, but the user of the function would have to call `reverse(head_of_the_list,Node.NIL)`, rather than `reverseList(head_of_the_list);`  The extra function is just a convenience function called once at the start to simplify usage.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive implementation based on dasblinkenlight's (love the handle!) suggestion: "A better approach is to change the signature of reverse to take the nodes created so far, in reverse order"

```
public class Node {
    private static final Node NIL=null; 

    public Node(int data, Node next) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    private int data;

    private Node next;

    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "";
        Node cur = this;
        while (cur != Node.NIL) {
            s += cur.data + ",";
            cur = cur.getNext();
        }
        return s;
    }

    /* Where the recursive magic happens */
    /* build the reversed list in the parameter 'reversed' */
    public Node reverse(Node n, Node reversed) 
    {
        if (n == Node.NIL) {
            return reversed;
        } else {
            return reverse(n.next,new Node(n.data,reversed));
        }
    }

    /* Kick off the recursion from the head node */
    public Node reverseList() {
        return reverse(this,Node.NIL);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        // Create a sample list
        Node n = new Node(1,new Node(12, new Node(34, new Node(3, Node.NIL))));

        System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println(n.reverseList());
    }

}
```